# Possible Research directions for students interested in Abstract Algebra

Tags: soft-question, education, online-resources

*This is my first post in MSE*:

I have completed my Masters in Mathematics.I love to do Abstract Algebra.
I have studied Groups,Rings,Fields,Modules and Non-Commutative Rings.
But I am weak in Calculus and I don't like doing stuffs like Real Analysis,Complex Analysis.

I want to do PhD in Abstract Algebra as I really want to study it further.

I checked the profiles of different faculty members in different Institutes.None mentioned Abstract Algebra in their profiles.

So I got a bit puzzled.

**Can someone please tell me about the topics which are closely related to Abstract Algebra or uses techniques from what I have studied and loved for example Rings,Modules etc as mentioned above.**

*To make it clear I am no way asking for Research Topics.*
I only want to find some suitable directions where I can continue studying Abstract Algebra

If this post is not suitable here,please tell me any other suitable site for this.

Comment: Which institutes did you check? Most math departments have at least a few people who do algebra of some sort.

Comment: Check also for *algebraic number theory*, or algebra and number theory.

Comment: Algebraic geometry is definitely something you should look into, and perhaps algebraic topology (although based on your comment re: analysis, you might not like that as much - but on the other hand, analysis and topology are very different things).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft;I checked faculty webpages of various institutes like MIT,Stanford and many others which were high in QS Rankings.But they all said algebraic geometry,representation theory etc.

Comment: @DietrichBurde; How should I prepare myself if I want to do PhD in Algebra,Number Theory and what are its prerequisites

Comment: @NoahSchweber; What are the topics that I need to study for Algebraic Geometry apart from Abstract Alg.

Comment: The google search ["research in algebra"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22research+in+algebra%22) gives a lot of results that seem relevant to what you want.

Comment: @UnderGrad_Student Prerequisites are basic algebra, commutative algebra, and algebraic structures.

Comment: If you like abstract algebra, you'll *love* cryptography.